# Best way to reference non-static methods that are in MainWindow, from a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, static

(Using WPF)

When writing code in a different class, I'd like to update the GUI resulting from it. I know it's bad practice to do so straight from other classes, but I'd like to reference methods that update it that are in MainWindow. How can I "find" the instance of MainWindow that is open?

Comment: Would you not pass it  to those classes as a parameter with 'this'?

Comment: @GarryVass I suppose I could. Is that most commonly done in the constructor, and just kept in a property?

Comment: it could be done in the constructor by passing in 'this', but your code might be more maintainable by passing an Action<T> instead.  It depends upon your style.  In the more contemporary WPF apps, people are using ViewModels and those can work with just about anything.  It's all down to your personal style.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Application.MainWindow property and cast it as appropriate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx

But I'm not saying this is the way you should do it, and you say yourself "it's bad practice to do so"